# Unable to select computed value from subquery results

Tags: mysql

My objective is to fetch some counts from another table, then calculate the difference and order by that difference to determine my top and least performing results.

```
select
    `id`,
    `subscriber_count`,
    ([SUBQUERY]) as `subscribed_count`,
    ([SUBQUERY]) as `unsubscribed_count`,
    (`subscribed_count` - `unsubscribed_count`) AS `difference`
from `mytable`
order by `difference` ASC
```

The problem is I'm getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'subscribed_count' in 'field list'
```

How can I order by the difference AND select it?

Comment: please check as error shows 'subscribed_count' not in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
select
    `id`,
    `subscriber_count`,
    ([SUBQUERY]) as `subscribed_count`,
    ([SUBQUERY]) as `unsubscribed_count`,
    (([SUBQUERY]) - ([SUBQUERY])) AS `difference`
from `mytable`
```

Issue :  subscribed_count, unsubscribed_count are not fields they are only aliases in mysql so could not make any operations from alias..

Thanks.
Hope it helps :)